# Why are there 5 E-mini S&P 500 Monday Weekly Options per months but only 4 E-mini S&P 500 Friday Weekly Options per month?

Tags: united-states, options

Why are there [5 E-mini S&P 500 Monday Weekly Options](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_contractSpecs_options.html?optionExpiration=U7#optionProductId=8292) per month (E1A,E2A,E3A,E4A,E5A) but only [4 E-mini S&P 500 Friday Weekly Options per month](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_contractSpecs_options.html?optionExpiration=U7#optionProductId=2915) (EW1,EW2,EW3,EW4) at the  [Chicago Mercantile Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Mercantile_Exchange) (CME)?

(There are also 5 Wednesday Weekly Options (E1C,E2C,E3C,E4C,E5C)).

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want them, you could ask the exchange to list them.  They may have discretion in their listing rules to add more expirations.

Usually they are bound by what their rules dictate as far as the listing schedule goes, but if there is sufficient interest they can probably change the rule.